# Dangers of overloading a 2.5A rated plug

Tags: maximum-ratings

Got  an old soviet samovar (tea kettle) and wanted to put a new plug on it as the sovet one doesn't plug into proper EU sockets.

I have a 2.5 A / 255v ungrounded plug, which I can use, but an curious as to how much current these plugs can actually take.

Likly the samovar is 2kW, so there will be short periods of 8ish amps boi going through it. And so far I haven't noticed it heating up.

Do you suspose that the plug is save? 
I opened the kettle itself and the inside is clearly more scary and dangerous than the plug sovet safety standards and age of the I insulation , but I'm curious to know if the plug can handle the load, as I'm sure it's rated at 2.5 but it's got more metal than the wire itself.

Comment: What's your hunch on why the plug is rated at 2.5 A? Why would you even consider using it ungrounded? Your question doesn't seem sensible.

Comment: The hunch is from the sticker on yhe side of the connector. The kettle is powered with its own unique soviet ungrounded power cord + plug thst goes into the kettle. I'd have to remove the plug+socket from the kettle and leave a large sharp hole where the plug was. Better to either leave it ungrounded or just remote cord and have it be a shelf peice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The risk is if the plug (or its contacts) heat up too much, they can cause a fire in the wall of your house.

I'd go buy a correctly rated plug rather than take that risk.

Also, if the wiring inside the appliance is "scary", you'd be wise to use a grounded plug and ground all user-accessible metal parts, to reduce the risk of shock.

Of course, to really reduce the risk of shock and fire, you'd be better off cutting the cord off this thing and displaying it on a shelf, while buying a new kettle with proper safety marks to make tea with.

Comment: Good points, but I'm curious as to the standard for the ratings of such plugs. Is it a load over n amps and it will start to heat up, or is it just a max rating for continuous use?

Comment: Every contact has resistance. The power dissipated in that resistance is given by \$ P = I^2R \$ so if you double the current you get four times the contact heat. You're considering using > three times the current so ...

Comment: Good point, I'll replace it with a higher rating. Looking at the old one it was only 6A, so likely it isn't a 2kw element, so not as bad as 16 times the power dissipated...

Comment: Also one point that of thought is that in the case of failure, it won't be a gradual heat up, but rather as it heats up its resistance will also increase, speeding up the heating, quickly leading to a fire. Still I'm curious as to if there's any info on failure points / conditions for such plugs / terminals, surly there must be some documented destructive  tests done.

Comment: @TonisF.Piip maybe the 6A plug is used because the soviet designer also thought "meeeh it will be fine" and overloaded it.

Comment: @Christian, or the 5 year plan doubled the number of 6A plugs made while halving the number of 2.5A plugs, so that was the only one available to the kettle factory.